# Connect to server via socket in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am pretty new to android app development, and I have created the following below my activity's onCreate():

```
public String test(){
    String test = "";
    try{
    Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("ipaddress"), port#);
    test +=(s.isConnected());

    BufferedReader readFromHost = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    readFromHost.ready();


    test += (readFromHost.readLine());
    s.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return test;

}
```

This then just routes to a:

```
textView2.setText(test());
```

But the string "test_message" which is grabbed from the server does not appear in the text view. However, When I just do

```
textView2.setText("hi");
```

It appears in the view, or if I run the test() in java outside of the android program the resulting "test_message" appears in console. Any thoughts on why it does not appear in the android runtime? Are ports treated differently? Any help would be great.

Attached is the LogCat. There appears to be a "NetworkOnMainThreadException"?

All that occurs in the program is you click a button which opens a new activity with the textview.

Log:

```
06-09 12:13:18.189: W/ApplicationPackageManager(4768): getCSCPackageItemText()
06-09 12:13:18.239: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(4768): Parent view is not a TextView
06-09 12:13:18.369: E/SpannableStringBuilder(4768): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-09 12:13:18.369: E/SpannableStringBuilder(4768): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-09 12:13:22.773: W/ApplicationPackageManager(4768): getCSCPackageItemText()

06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1156)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity.test(DisplayMessageActivity.java:42)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity.onCreate(DisplayMessageActivity.java:31)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
06-09 12:13:22.783: W/System.err(4768):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 12:13:22.803: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(4768): Parent view is not a TextView
```

Comment: Does logcat say anything?

Comment: @Foxinsocks "network operation in UI thread" perhaps?

Comment: @harism add full log to your question.

Comment: You must spawn a separate thread to do network I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do network requests in the `Main Thread`. Create your own `Thread` and get string from server:

```
private TextView textView2;

public void test(){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();
            try{
                Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("ipaddress"), 1111);
                test.append(s.isConnected());

                BufferedReader readFromHost = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                readFromHost.ready();


                test.append(readFromHost.readLine());
                s.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView2.setText(test.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Interesting. So it works and I connect, but the setText line throws a null pointer exception (and the app crashes). Using Log.i test actually does have the proper information and is not set to null.

Comment: @DeeVu So `textView2 == null`.

Comment: Got it working. Thanks a lot for your help. My implementation was throwing several errors because of the nature of threads and having the need to have final variables. Fixed it by having the line read `((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview)).setText(test.toString());`